# Possible error in Select statement

Tags: apex

I have written a customer controller for a VisualForce page which displays all the Contact records associated with a particular Account. When manually testing the VisualForce page everything seems to work fine. All of the Contacts are displayed as I want them to be.

However, when I write some test code, my SELECT statement doesn't pull out my test Contact that I've associated with my test Account. I'm wondering whether it is to do with the way that I have written my SELECT statement.

My SELECT statement:

```
[SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Salutation, Title, Primary__c, To_Be_Deleted__c 
                    FROM Contact 
                    WHERE Contact.Account.Id = :accountID
                    AND To_Be_Deleted__c = false];
```

Some setup code in my test class:

```
Account acc = new Account(name = 'Test Account');
Contact validPrimaryContact = getValidActiveContact();
validPrimaryContact.Primary__c = true;
validPrimaryContact.Account = acc;

insert acc;
insert validPrimaryContact;
```

Debugging Log showing that no rows have been found for that select statement:

```
16:00:36.448 (1448431000)|CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[18]|01pP000000058yE|<init>(String,String)
16:00:36.448 (1448781000)|METHOD_ENTRY|[28]|01pP000000058yE|ContactCleanupController.init()
16:00:36.448 (1448858000)|USER_DEBUG|[38]|DEBUG|accountID: 001P000000Z1iPjIAJ
16:00:36.448 (1448901000)|USER_DEBUG|[39]|DEBUG|returnID: 001P000000Z1iPjIAJ
16:00:36.448 (1448925000)|METHOD_ENTRY|[40]|01pP000000058yE|ContactCleanupController.selectOnlyActiveContacts()
16:00:36.449 (1449424000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[130]|Aggregations:0|select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Salutation, Title, Primary__c, To_Be_Deleted__c from Contact where (Contact.Account.Id = :tmpVar1 and To_Be_Deleted__c = false)
16:00:36.456 (1456474000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[130]|Rows:0
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Is it something to do with `Contact.Account.Id`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you should insert the account and then assign the Id to the contact.  So I'd rearrange thus:

```
Account acc = new Account(name = 'Test Account');
insert acc;    

Contact validPrimaryContact = getValidActiveContact();
validPrimaryContact.Primary__c = true;
validPrimaryContact.Account = acc.Id;

insert validPrimaryContact;
```

Also, I don't know what you're doing in `getValidActiveContact()` but be aware that you have no access to existing contacts in your org for the duration of the test.  Therefore if you haven't explicitly inserted a new contact that will likely return nothing.

Comment: Awesome. I take on board your comment regarding the `getValidActiveContact()` method. In fact, it is just a method to build a Contact that I know to be valid, which I will then insert into the database for the test. But I appreciate the reminder that there are no initial records in testing code. Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: I realised after I added the comment that you may be using it for that. I do the same, using a helper class for setting up known-good test data.  My method is a little different as I pass the Account.Id in to the method but like you leave the actual insert outside of the method.